# MSYS error "rem: command not found"

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin, msys

I am getting this error "rem:command not found" in my batch file. Other dos commands (e.g. echo) are also not found.

My makefile is calling this batch file. This works previously when I am using cygwin. But when I changed to MSYS, I am getting this error. Anyone know why this is?

I am using MSYS version 1.0.17 on a Windows pc. But, I did not install Mingw. Should i install it also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are trying to run a "Batch" file using Bash. This will not work. While Batch file interprets `rem` as a comment, Bash simply thinks it is a command and tries to run it.

My suggest would be to rewrite it as a Bash script, perhaps [**this**](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html) could be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

After trying with  **cmd //c [path_to_bat file]** it works for me.
This is because mingw cannot run *.bat file directly after running *.bat file with cmd it works.

I found following mail thread about this type of issue
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2003-10/msg00323.html